# Best Way To Test For Correct JSON Serialization

Tags: java, json, testing, serialization, jackson

I use the Jackson library with Java to serialize POJOs to JSON and vice versa.  Let's say that I am running some tests where I am serializing an object and I know that the expected JSON string is `{"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"}`. What is the best way to validate that my object serialized to the above string? Or better yet, what is the best way to validate that each of the fields is what I expect?

I have tried simply hard coding that string in and doing a comparison, but I have had cases where I serialize to JSON -> deserialize to POJO -> then serialize the deserialized POJO back to JSON again, and the fields are out of order. Then the string comparison fails even though all of the fields are correct.

**Is there are better/different way to verify that my JSON string has the expected fields in it when testing?**

Comment: You are not writing the json jackson library, so you should test only your code. But if you liuke to be sure you can serialize your object to a json, deserialize it to an object and verify that the original object is equals to the new one.

Comment: user `java.lang.String` function `contains()` or you can user regx to validate

Comment: Serialize to a `JsonNode`, read from a file as a `JsonNode` and use .equals()!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the exact same situation as you and found [JSONassert](https://github.com/skyscreamer/JSONassert) to be very helpful.

In your JUnit test you would have to add something like this:

```
String actual = getSerializedContent();
String expected = "{firstName:\"John\", lastName:\"Doe\"}";
JSONAssert.assertEquals(expected, actual, false);
```